# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen (Errno :: EACCES) error when trying to execute Ruby program via RubyMine 2019.1

Tags: ruby, windows-10, rubymine, ruby-2.5

I'm trying to execute a Ruby program `(Ruby v2.5.3)` on Windows 10 where I basically open a file `(sample1.txt, sample2.txt)` and append its contents (a list of 3 names) to an empty file `(result.txt)` and later sort the contents of file `result.txt` (entire code below). However, when I run this code on RubyMine 2019.1, I get an error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:5:in `<main>'
        5: from C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:5:in `each'
        4: from C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
        3: from C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:7:in `each'
        2: from C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        1: from C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:8:in `open'
C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb:8:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - result.txt (Errno::EACCES)
```

All files have full permissions. However, when I execute the same code via the IRB terminal it works perfectly fine.

I've just started working on Ruby and I couldn't find the solution to this problem anywhere. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
file_array = ["sample1.txt", "sample2.txt"]

file_array.each do |x|
  file = File.open(x,'r')
  file.each do |h|
  open('result.txt', 'a') do |f|
    puts f << h
  end
  end
  open('result.txt','a') do |f|
    puts f << "\n"
  end
  end

new_array = File.readlines('result.txt').sort
File.open('result.txt','w') do |file|
  new_array.each {|n| file.puts(n)}
end
```

Comment: Where is your project directory located? on `Desktop` folder?

Comment: its in `C:/Users/tanveer.dey/RubymineProjects/src/Assignment9.rb`

Comment: Try moving the project to `C:/` and then execute the code.

Comment: This too results in same error.

Answer (score 2):

Found the fix! The issue occurs because the file `result.txt`, to which the contents are being "written" to, is specified "with" the extension `(.txt)`. Removing the extension from the file operations which involves writing solves the issue. Below code without the extension now works perfectly.

```
file_array.each do |x|
  file = File.open(x,'r')
  file.each do |h|
  open('result', 'a') do |f|
    puts f << h
  end
  end
  open('result','a') do |f|
    puts f << "\n"
  end
  end

new_array = File.readlines('result').sort
File.open('result','w') do |file|
  new_array.each {|n| file.puts(n)}
end
```